# How do I prove a claim on a recursive formula?

Tags: induction, recursion

I have to prove that $F(n) \le n^2 $  for n $\ge$ 1

with $i\le 2: F(i)= i$

and for $i>2, F(i) = i + 0.5*F(i-1) +0.5*F(i-2) $

After doing some research, I am pretty confident that I have to use induction, I know how to prove my base cases and what IH to use but I get stuck at the last part of the proof. This is how far I've gotten:

$\text{Base case: }\; F(1) = 1 $ and $1 \le 1^2$

$\text{Base case: }\; F(2) = 2 $ and $2 \le 2^2$

$IH: F(i)\le i^2$ holds and $F(i-1)\le (i-1)^2$ holds for $n\ge1$

To show: $F(i+1)\le(i+1)^2$

$F(i+1) = (i+1) + 0.5*F(i) + 0.5*F(i-1)$

By IH: $0.5*F(i) + 0.5*F(i-1) \le 0.5*(i^2 + (i-1)^2)$

My question now is, what do I do with the i+1 since I have no assumptions about this and I also do not know where to get them. And how do I get to what I have now on the right hand side to $(i+1)^2$

Comment: You just need to press on. Expanding the expression you have gives $i^2-i+\frac{1}{2}$. Adding $i+1$ gives $i^2+\frac{3}{2}<(i+1)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done.

**Inductive step.** Suppose the claim holds for $n$ and $n-1$. Let us prove it for $n+1$.

You have

$$F(n+1)=n+1+\frac12(F(n)+F(n-1))\le n+1+\frac12(n^2+(n-1)^2)$$

by inductive hypotesis. A few calculations yield:
$$F(n-1)\le n^2+\frac32<n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$$